# More information about maven update

Tags: eclipse, maven

Whenever I make changes in Eclipse to a project I am working on, I have to rebuild.  There are actually several projects involved.  I always do

maven update, maven clean (each project), maven install(each project).

I was wondering whether maven update does the clean and install so that these steps are not necessary for me to do or is update different.  I read some pages on update, but was not quite sure.

If it is important, these are Java projects with Eclipse.

Comment: You don't have to invoke Maven at all if you are working from Eclipse. You should be able to just run your application from Eclipse.

Comment: Oh sorry.  I do, but sometimes I have to build a jar file and send it to other people.  The jar has everything needed (i.e. an executable, etc) as the testers will not be using Eclipse.  But even with Eclipse don't I need to rebuild any time code changes are made?  I know in some other projects I don't, but in these it seems I do.

Comment: What is maven update? Do you mean _Maven -> Update Project..._? This has nothing do with the build. You should use it only if your maven files are modified outside of Eclipse and you want to refresh them.

Comment: Yes. maven -> update project.  OK thanks.